# Receber id de uma option de autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellij-idea, autocompletar

Tenho o seguinte autocomplete definido no `HTML`

**HTML**

```
<label class="input">
  <input type="text" list="list" id="entidade" placeholder="Cliente" onblur="dadosCliente ( )">
  <datalist id="list">
    @for(entidade <- entidades) {
    <option name="ent" id="@entidade.getId()" value="@entidade.getNome()">@entidade.getNome()</option>
 }
</datalist> </label>
```

O autocomplete está a funcionar bem, os dados da BD estão a ser buscados. Como é que posso agora em `jQUERY` ir buscar o ID do elemento selecionado?

Já tentei isto: `$("option[name=ent] :selected").attr('id');` mas retorna undefined. Alguma Sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Funconamento do dataList é um pouco diferente do select, você terá que filtrar manualmente o dataList.

abaixo segue um exemplo com um dataList:

**HTML**

```
<input id="txtID" list="ent" />
<datalist id="ent">    
    <option id="001" value="Valor 001"></option>
    <option id="002" value="Valor 002"></option>
    <option id="003" value="Valor 003"></option>
    <option id="004" value="Valor 004"></option>
</datalist>
<button id="btGetID">Get ID</button>
<br />
<label id="lblID"></label>
```

**JS**

```
var btGetID = $("#btGetID");
var lblID = $("#lblID");
var txtID = $("#txtID");
var dataList = $("#ent");

btGetID.click(function () {
    var value = txtID.val();
    var option = $("option", dataList).filter(function () {
        return this.value == value;
    });
    console.log(option);
    lblID.html(option.attr("id"));
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c8Lkxf0m/1/)

Comment: Não me parece que seja isso, voltou a retornar undefined :S

Comment: neste caso não deve ter nenhuma option com a propriedade selected.

Comment: Eu nem sei se esse selected é bem aplicado, eu quero é ir buscar o id do nome que fui buscar ao autocomplete.

Comment: não tinha notado que se tratava de um dataList e não de um select. vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo fornecido. De qualquer das formas, o exemplo acima encaixa muito bem no que pretendo. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Se você tentar colocar o valor de "name" entre aspas?

`$("option[name='ent'] :selected").attr('id');`

Editado:

Alias, se você fizer `function dadosCliente(){ $(this).val(); }` não vai funcionar melhor?

Editado 2:
A "única" solução que eu achei, baseando-me nas informações que você passou, foi:

`$("#entidade").blur(function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();
    $("#list option").each(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == valor )
            console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
    });
});`

Comment: Continua 'undefined' :s se eu tirar o ':selected' retorna-me sempre o valor 2, não sei porque razão

Comment: veja a edição da minha resposta

Comment: dessa forma aparece: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: o que tem na função dadosCliente?
Ela é usada mais de uma vez?

Comment: Não ela só é usada ao perder o foco desse campo, mais nada, e neste momento só estou a tentar ir buscar o id do item que escolhi por autocomplete. tenho var nome = $('#entidade').val(); que me retorna o nome que selecionei para esse campo.

Comment: lembre-se de colocar a função dentro de `$(document).ready()`
Ou então no onblur passar o this.value na função, e na função receber como uma variável

Comment: A solução do Editado2 Eestá a funcionar muito bem. Muito Obrigado